# Slide up animation overlays fragment instead of animating both fragments in the same time

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, mobile

Hy guys,

I've got a problem with an animation. I've got 2 fragments (A and B). A button in fragment A takes me to fragment B. I would like to get both fragments to animate up in the transition. The problem I've got, fragment B animates up covering fragment A, instead of both animating up. Here is my code:

slide in up animation

```
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:propertyName="y"
    android:valueFrom="100%"
    android:valueTo="0%"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

slide out up

```
  <translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:propertyName="y"
    android:valueFrom="0%"
    android:valueTo="-100%"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

and the method in code:

```
    public void showB() {

    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up)
            .add(R.id.content, B.newInstanceAdd())
            .commit();
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace the fragment use :

```
replace(R.id.content, B.newInstanceAdd())
```

instead of:

```
add(R.id.content, B.newInstanceAdd())
```

Otherwise it's up to you to hide/detach the previous fragment.